# Entity Framework Core LazyLoading returning null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I working a project and i need use lazyloading i installed package and configure,query working but relationship columns returned null. How to i can use lazyloading?

Installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies(version 5.0.7)

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString");
                optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies(true);

            }
        }
```

**My Models(I make with DB First)**

```
 public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
         
        }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }

        virtual public Company Company { get; set; }
        virtual public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
    
public partial class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {
            Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
        }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TaxNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

**Used Method:**

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            using (dbContext context = new dbContext())
            {
               return context.Customers.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The visible code doesn't give any reason to think that lazy loading wouldn't work, and unfortunately it's not clear where you have a problem. What's the meaning of "relationship columns returned null"?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy), lazy loading should be implemented in this way

Install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions` package too and change the implementation:

```cs
public partial class Customer
{
    private ICollection<Orders> _orders;

    public Customer()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public Customer(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
    {
        LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }

    private ILazyLoader LazyLoader { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }

    virtual public Company Company { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders
    {
        get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _orders);
        set => _orders = value;
    }
}
```

And after iterating on orders data will be fetched

```cs
using(var db = new YourContext())
{
    var customers = db.Customers.ToList();
    foreach(var customer in customers )
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Customer: {customer.Name} {customer .LastName}");
        foreach(var order in customer.Ortders) // lazy loading initiated
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{order.Id}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for help, I remake and I have a exception:

Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Can not instantiate proxy of class: MyProjectName.Models.Customer.
Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyLoader

Comment: I update the answer and check it again, please.

Answer (score -1):

Better way to use lazy load is that , we used Lazy loading without proxies, according to Microsoft document [Lazy loading without proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy#lazy-loading-without-proxies).

When EF try to create object from your class ,It call your model constructor that have no argument ,then `lazyLoader` service did not fill.
you most remove empty constructor And just keep that one with `lazyLoader`:

```
public Customer(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
{
    LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
}
```

Your model class most be like this :

```
public partial class Customer
{
    private ICollection<Orders> _orders;
    private ILazyLoader LazyLoader { get; set; }

    public Customer(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
    {
        LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }
 
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders
    {
        get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _orders);
        set => _orders = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's an alternative and certainly not objectively "better".